# How to replace string with collection of elements in DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

There is a method to replace string in the body

```
body.replaceText('{zip}', client.zip);
```

What would be the best way to to replace string with collection of elements?
My attempt:

```
function billing(body) {
    var coll = body.findText("{coll}").getElement();
    var collList = new Array("apple", "pear", "cherry");

    for (i=0; i < billList.length; i++) {
        bills.appendListItem(billList[i]);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: `billList` isn't defined anywhere in the script. Did you mean `collList`? What is the result that you expect? If you script isn't working you should include the textual error message.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i meant good catch                      
`
    function billing(body) {
        var coll = body.findText("{coll}").getElement();
        var collList = new Array("apple", "pear", "cherry");

        for (i=0; i < collList.length; i++) {
            bills.appendListItem(billList[i]);
        }
        return "";
    }
`